# width of <a> element into a <li> element

Tags: html, css

I have a link into a li element, and I would like my  element to have the same size (100%) than his parent (li).

This is my code, I'm using HTML5, CSS3 and AngularJS (don't know if it's important ^^) :

```
<ul id="music-list">
    <li ng-repeat="music in musics" class="music-li">
        <a href="{{music.url}}" class="music-link"><strong>{{music.artiste}}</strong> - {{music.titre}}</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And CSS :

```
.music-li{
    list-style-type: none !important;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #183152;
    color: #E1E6FA;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-top: 2px;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.music-li:hover{
    background-color: #ABC8E2;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.music-link > a {
    width: 100%;
}

.music-link{
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

[image]

As you could see in the picture, my  isn't full width.

Comment: `.music-link > a` - that selector matches nothing - your link element itself has the class `music-link`, and it does of course not contain another link itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change the selector of this rule:

```
.music-link > a {
    width: 100%;
}
```

It has to be `a.music-link`, since `.music-link` is the class of the `a`element itself, not its child. Also, add `display: block`, as isherwood wrote:

```
a.music-link {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, my selector was very useless .. Sorry .. It's working now, thank you ! :)

Answer (score 3):

You can't set the width on an inline element. Do something like this:

```
li a {display: block;}
```

Comment: I tried but it doen't change nothing. Actually I would like something like when I click on the li element, then it actives the link

Comment: You'd need scripting to create a click event on the list item.